# Finding $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 2}\frac{\sqrt{x^3+1}-\sqrt{4x+1}}{\sqrt{x^3-2x}-\sqrt{x+2}}$

Tags: calculus, limits

I came across this question.

> Evaluate the limit  $$ \lim_{x \to 2}\frac{\sqrt{x^3+1}-\sqrt{4x+1}}{\sqrt{x^3-2x}-\sqrt{x+2}}$$

I tried rationalizing the denominator, substitution, yet nothing seems to cancel out with the denominator. I don't think we are supposed to use squeeze theorem or L'Hopital rule for this.

Can someone give me a hint in the right direction?

Comment: Rationalize by multiplying $$\frac{(\sqrt{x^3+1} + \sqrt{4x+1})(\sqrt{x^3-2x}+\sqrt{x+2})}{(\sqrt{x^3+1} + \sqrt{4x+1})(\sqrt{x^3-2x}+\sqrt{x+2})}.$$

Comment: Thank you! I found the solution. If I have time, I will answer my own question.

Comment: Its a 0/0 form, so I guess we are good to apply L'Hopital rule as well.

Comment: Well technically they haven't taught L'Hopital's Rule, and I can imagine it can get very messy. Anyways we are encouraged not to use L'Hopital's Rule

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$${{\sqrt{x^3+1}-\sqrt{4x+1} \over \sqrt{x^3-2x} - \sqrt{x+2}}  
= \left({\sqrt{x^3+1}-\sqrt{4x+1} \over \sqrt{x^3-2x} - \sqrt{x+2}} \right)
\left( {\sqrt{x^3+1}+\sqrt{4x+1} \over \sqrt{x^3+1}+\sqrt{4x+1}} \right) 
\left({\sqrt{x^3-2x} + \sqrt{x+2} \over \sqrt{x^3-2x} + \sqrt{x+2}} \right) 
=\left({x^3-4x \over x^3-3x-2}\right)
\left({\sqrt{x^3-2x}+\sqrt{x+2} \over \sqrt{x^3+1}+\sqrt{4x+1}} \right)  
=\left({x(x+2) \over (x+1)^2}\right)
\left({\sqrt{x^3-2x}+\sqrt{x+2} \over \sqrt{x^3+1}+\sqrt{4x+1}} \right)}$$

At $x=2$, above simplified to:

$\displaystyle \left({2 \times 4 \over 3 \times 3}\right) 
\left({2+2 \over 3+3} \right) = \left({8 \over 9}\right) \left({2 \over 3}\right) = {16 \over 27}$

Comment: Nice, today I learnt a new technique of doing limit questions

Answer (score 1):

*Using a small trick that I enjoy.*

Let $x=t+2$ to make
$$y=\frac{\sqrt{x^3+1}-\sqrt{4x+1}}{\sqrt{x^3-2x}-\sqrt{x+2}}=\frac{\sqrt{4 t+9}-\sqrt{t^3+6 t^2+12 t+9}}{\sqrt{t+4}-\sqrt{t^3+6 t^2+10 t+4}}$$ and now use the binomial expansion or Taylor series around $t=0$.

We have
$$\sqrt{4 t+9}=3+\frac{2 t}{3}-\frac{2 t^2}{27}+O\left(t^3\right)$$
$$\sqrt{t^3+6 t^2+12 t+9}=3+2 t+\frac{t^2}{3}+O\left(t^3\right)$$
$$\sqrt{t+4}=2+\frac{t}{4}-\frac{t^2}{64}+O\left(t^3\right)$$
$$\sqrt{t^3+6 t^2+10 t+4}=2+\frac{5 t}{2}-\frac{t^2}{16}+O\left(t^3\right)$$
So
$$y=\frac{-\frac{4 t}{3}-\frac{11 t^2}{27}+O\left(t^3\right) } {-\frac{9 t}{4}+\frac{3 t^2}{64}+O\left(t^3\right) }$$ Now, using the long division
$$y=\frac{16}{27}+\frac{47 }{243}t+O\left(t^2\right)$$ which shows the limit and also how it is approached.

Comment: Long division step might not be necessary.  Just divide y numerator and denominator by t. At t=0, y = (-4/3) / (-9/4) = 16/27

Comment: @albertchan. This is a key point to me. If you have time to waste, have a look at  https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/8339/teaching-limits-and-asymptotics-at-the-same-time